# Wrapper does not expand until all data is loaded

Tags: css

On this image I labeled in red #container1 and its child #container2. #container2 has three column divs labeled in blue.

I took this snapshot in the moment both containers were not expanded because of delayed load of external apps (addThis, Facebook, Adsense). After that both containers expand as expected. Anyway, I always see pictures (col2) and col1 displaying before #container2 is expanded. (fraction of a second delay but it exists)

[image: Descriptive Sample]

```
#container1{
text-align:center;
width:926px; 
padding:15px; margin-left:12px; 
margin-bottom:10px; 
border:thin solid #999; 
-moz-border-radius:20px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
border-radius:20px;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #CCC;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #CCC; 
min-heigt:950px
}



#container2 {
width: 980px;
text-align:left; /* reset text alignment */ 
margin:0 auto; 
position:relative; 
background-color:white;
border: thin solid #999;/*#69c7e8;*/
border-top:none;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px #CCC, -5px 5px 8px #CCC, 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px #CCC, -5px 5px 8px #CCC, 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px #CCC, -5px 5px 8px #CCC, 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
min-height:1000px;
}

#col_1{
float:left;
width:200px; 
margin-left:0;
text-align:left; 
}

#col_2{
float:left; 
width:566px;
text-align:left;  
}

#col_3{
float:right;
width:160px; 
margin-right:0;
text-align:left; }
```

As you can see in the picture #container1 expands immediately to its min-height value while #container2 does not.
Anyway I don't like this patch using min-height.

Is it possible to expand both containers at the same time contents are displayed?

Comment: Just to point out that you have a typo in `#container1`: `min-heigt:950px` should be `min-height`.

Comment: You are right. This was a distraction. Anyway they both expand after some content is displayed